# One-liner in Swift for safe initialization of @IBInspectables

Tags: ios, properties, initialization, swift

I love the new `@IBInspectable` concept in XCode 6 and I also love the great options for ensuring type-safety that Swift brings to iOS/OS X development.

But here's a common thing I will do very often during development and as all of this is very new I'd like to figure out *the best way of doing it*: It should be ***safe*** **and** ***short***. A one liner would be great here because then every property of a class would be defined within one line which would (in my opinion) make classes much more readable.

As Apple has showed off that Swift was built to make safety short (see the the next few seconds in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7dD75rPZH4&t=1m48s)) I think it should be possible somehow. Here's an example of what I'm doing right now:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomViewClass: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var iconImageView: UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet var separatorView: UIView?
    @IBInspectable var iconImage: UIImage? { didSet { self.iconImageView!.image = self.iconImage } }
    @IBInspectable var separatorColor: UIColor = UIColor.grayColor() { didSet { self.separatorView!.backgroundColor = self.separatorColor } }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

This is ***short*** but ***not type-safe***: If e.g. `self.iconImageView` is `nil` then this code will have unsafe behavior. From Swift I would expect something  like this:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomViewClass: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var iconImageView: UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet var separatorView: UIView?
    @IBInspectable var iconImage: UIImage? { didSet { self.iconImageView?.image = self.iconImage } }
    @IBInspectable var separatorColor: UIColor = UIColor.grayColor() { didSet { self.separatorView?.backgroundColor = self.separatorColor } }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Realize that `self.iconImageView!` was replaced by `self.iconImageView?` where I expect `self.iconImageView?.image = self.iconImage` to do something like this but in one line:

```
if self.iconImageView? {
    self.iconImageView!.image = self.iconImage
}
```

Does anyone have a solution? Or is this currently not possible so we should file a radar about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release notes of XCode 6 Beta 5 state the following:

> The ? chaining operator can also be used to conditionally assign
>   through an optional if it has a value:

```
 sequences["fibonacci"]?.append(0)
 sequences["fibonacci"]?[6] = 13
 sequences["perfect"]?[0] = 6
 // Does nothing because the sequence has no 'perfect' key
```

> Note that properties that are optional as a result of lookup through
>   AnyObject cannot be mutated yet.

This means my expected approach should work from now on:

```
@IBInspectable var iconImage: UIImage? { didSet { self.iconImageView?.image = self.iconImage } }
```